# How to hide sliding div with css

Tags: html, css, styles, hover, effects

I would like to create a sliding effect. I have two divs that are placed beside. When hovering `div id="left"` that slides right and hides `div id="right"`. Around `div id="left"` there is something like a mousetracker that adds some space around `div id="left"` for additional place that can be hovered to hide `div id="right"`. I built an example to show what I mean:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rpvHL/)

Below is the HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="tracker">
        <div id="left">slides right</div>    
        <div id="right">should disappear only when hover red div</div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS for the slide effect:

```
/*Sliding Effects:*/
#tracker:hover #left {
    margin-left: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-duration: 2s;
}
#tracker:hover #right {
   visibility:hidden;
}
#tracker:hover {
   width: 400px;
   height: 200px;
   margin-top: -25px;
   padding-top: 25px;
}
```

Now the problem is that the effect starts even when hovering `div id="right"`. So I still don't know how to solve this issue.

I really would appreciate if there is someone who could help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect starts even when hovering `div#right` because it is a `div#tracker` child and the hover effect is bublling up to the parent.

To achieve what you want only using css you need to change its DOM position. Using your example I had to change the following to make it work:

- `div#right` is now a `div#tracker` sibling
- `#tracker, #left, #right` div elements are now absolute positioned
- since `div#right` is now a sibling and not a child of `div#tracker` I changed the following css selector
  `#tracker:hover #right { }` to `#tracker:hover + #right { }`

[DEMO (using your example)](http://jsfiddle.net/rpvHL/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was able to make the animation of the red box trigger only if you hover over it by adding a container around it (`#left-outer`) with the same width and height and adding `overflow:hidden;`

see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/N4X5P/

I hope I was able to help!

Comment: hello and thanks for anwering but this was not the main goal to my question. the effect starts also when hovering the grey div. so what you did is not what i would like to archieve.